# Find the maximum and minimum of $f(x,y) = x^2 -xy +y^2$ subject to constraints $|x|+|y|\leq1$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the maximum and minimum of $f(x,y) = x^2 -xy +y^2$ subject to constraints $|x|+|y|\leq1$.

---

The constraint of this exercise came out of left field for me, I'm not sure how to handle it. Note, we have not gone through Lagrangian multipliers yet, so an approach without them would be preferable.

To get started somewhere, I began by computing the gradient, obtaining the following:
$$[2x-y \hspace{3mm} 2y-x]$$
Thus we can see that for a critical point, we require that $2x=y$ and $2y=x$, which leads to $x=y=0$ and $(0,0)$ is a critical point contained inside our restriction. But then I'm not sure how to proceed.

Apologies for the lack of an attempt, but I'm simply not sure how to go about this in a systematic way, so any input would be much apriciated!

Comment: Do you know how to procced when you forget about the constraints? What type of critical point is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $x^2-xy+y^2 = \left(x - \dfrac{y}{2}\right)^2 +\dfrac{3y^2}{4}\ge 0$ , for all reals $x,y$ in region $D$ defined by: $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: |x|+|y| \le 1\}$,  and is $0$ when $x = 0 = y$. Thus the min value is $0$. For The max value is $1$. Observe that $x^2 - xy + y^2 \le x^2 + 2|x||y| + y^2 = (|x|+|y|)^2 \le 1$. This value occurs when $x = \pm1, y = 0$ or $x = 0, y = \pm1$.

**Note:** We can show that $0$ is the greatest lower bound for $f(x,y) = x^2-xy+y^2$ on $D$. For if there is a lower bound of $f$ that is greater than $0$, call it $c$. Then $0 < c < 1$. Thus choose $(x,y) = (c,0)$, then $f(c,0) = c^2 - c\cdot 0 + 0^2 = c^2 < c$. Thus $c$ is no longer a lower bound. This means $c$ is the greatest lower bound for $f$ and this lower bound can be attained at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ hence it is the min value as well.